# How to search a Mongo collection for a document that contains an array that contains an element that meets a particular criteria?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new at Mongo and there might be a better way to do what I want.  I'm dealing with a particular data structure that my application must process.

Suppose that I have a collection that contains two documents that contain information about universities and their student clubs to include the name of each club and the name of each student in each club along with their age:

```
{
    _id: 1, // object ID
    name: "Oxford University",
    clubs: [{
        name: "Soccer",
        members: [{
                name: "Alice",
                age: 22
            },
            {
                name: "Bob",
                age: 23
            }
        ]
    }, {
        name: "Gymnastics",
        members: [{
                name: "Charlie",
                age: 20
            },
            {
                name: "Dorothy",
                age: 19
            }
        ]
    }]
}

{
    _id: 2, // object ID
    name: "Cambridge University",
    clubs: [{
        name: "Chess",
        members: [{
                name: "Ellen",
                age: 30
            },
            {
                name: "Frank",
                age: 35
            }
        ]
    }, {
        name: "Go",
        members: [{
                name: "Gilbert",
                age: 25
            },
            {
                name: "Hikari",
                age: 40
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Suppose that I want to write a query on this collection that will find universities that have a club that has at least one member aged 40 or older.

How do I do that?

I sketched this example based off of the idea of taking some JSON documents and inserting them into a new collection.  Maybe it would be a better idea to break this apart into multiple collections.  I just had the idea to research if Mongo might be a good product to use in this situation given that a big part of my job here is to create something that can receive some JSON data, process it, and make it queryable.

Comment: Do you mean something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/USdB4DrdEY0)?

Comment: You've given the answer I need, @rickhg12s.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB queries have a convenient feature to query documents that have a specific value or condition in embedded objects and arrays.  In the query you can specify the "path" to the object or array using "dot notation" without having to specify the exact array index, etc.

Using your example, you can find the documents where a member of a club is aged 40 or older like this.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "clubs.members.age": {
    "$gte": 40
  }
})
```

This returns the second document in your example collection.

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/USdB4DrdEY0).